# Http V1 api FCM is working fine in Development version but showing error in Play Store Version

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated to http v1 api FCM from http legacy. It is working fine delivering the notification  with the development version but when I uploaded to Play store and checked it is showing error  [8175] a.a: unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/messages:send
After migration both the http v1 api is enabled as well as http legacy api  kindly help

should I disable the http legacy api after migration